# And yet another javascript clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I've seen a bunch of these threads and went through a few of them but nothing seemed to be of help so far. So I'm trying to call the timer continuously while the ajax call is taking place. Once the ajax call reaches the complete event, I'd like to clearInterval the timer, but that doesn't seem to be working because the call to CheckProgress() keeps going and going.

Here's my code:

```
var timer = "";

        $("#ChartUpdateData").click(function () {
            $("#loadingimgfeatdiv").show(); //ajax loading gif
            if (timer == "")
            {
                console.log("Starting Progress Checks...");
                timer = window.setInterval("CheckProgress()", 5000);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: '@(Url.Action("UpdateServerData","Charts"))',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                },
                complete:function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    $("#loadingimgfeatdiv").hide();
                    StopCheckingProgress();
                    LoadChart();
                },
            });

        });

    function StopCheckingProgress()
    {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        timer = "";
        console.log("Ending Progress Checks...");
    }
    function CheckProgress()
    {
        console.log("Checking Progress...");
        console.log(timer);
    }
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your `complete` function is ever called? This may just be a problem with your AJAX request, and nothing to do with `setInterval()`.

Comment: 100% certain its working. I can see         console.log("Ending Progress Checks..."); is being processed. I added an image of firebug to help show whats going on.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. Why do you need those timers in the first place, when you can handle everything with the events that $.ajax gives you?

Comment: `setInterval(CheckProgress, 5000)` is the correct declaration. Passing a string is a deprecated form. Also, make sure you're clicking more than once, otherwise you're losing the reference to your original timer.

Comment: @zzzzBov Can you elaborate a little on what you mean about clicking more then once? I'm not but I think timer is global :( So I think whatever you're talking about might be the issue.

Comment: @topek I can't say I'm 100% familiar with all the options of $.ajax but what I'm trying to do is create a progress bar for the UpdateServerData. Inside the CheckProgress function, I'm going to request the current status of the Update and use that to construct a progress bar.

Comment: @Robodude, if you click once, timer will be set to a timer index (just an int) when `setInterval` is called. If you click a second time, before `clearInterval` is called, you'll lose your reference to the active timer because it will be overwritten with a *second* timer index. `StopCheckingProgress` will clear the second timer, but the first one will continue on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just checked and it uses the same id from start to finish and it still doesn't work, so that doesn't seem to be the issue...

Comment: @Robodude - What parts of the above code are running within `$(document).ready()`? I don't think you've shown all the code here, and the reason this isn't working is very likely due to variable scope issues.

Comment: @nrabinowitz The click event handlers are inside the $(document).ready(){}); The functions as well as the var timer declaration are outside it. If it matters, the var timer is at the very top of the page and the functions are at the bottom of the page (after the document ready)

Comment: @Robodude - OK, then I'm flummoxed :(. Your code works entirely as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/BV8Ba/3/ (fork of @Tomasz). So something you haven't included here is going wrong.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Thanks for looking into it a bit further! I really don't know what it could be. Do you know anything about MVC3? Could there be issues related to having some other code in partial views? (All the code for this example is on the same page though...)

Comment: @Robodude - if it's a front-end problem, I try to ignore the back-end system - the rendered front-end code is all that matters. Your back-end framework shouldn't affect what happens in the front-end page, except in the code it produces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never liked setInterval. I like managing timers directly.

```
var timerStop = false

$("#ChartUpdateData").click(function () {
    $("#loadingimgfeatdiv").show(); //ajax loading gif
    if (!timerStop) {
        console.log("Starting Progress Checks...");
        CheckProgress()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '@(Url.Action("UpdateServerData","Charts"))',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        },
        complete:function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $("#loadingimgfeatdiv").hide();
            timerStop = true;
        },
    });

});

function CheckProgress()  {
    if(timerStop) {
        console.log("Ending Progress Checks...");
        return;
    }
    console.log("Checking Progress...");
    console.log(timer);
    window.setTimeout(function(){CheckProgress()}, 5000);
}
```

Comment: at least use `window.setTimeout(CheckProgress, 5000);` as we have all come to understand and love here

Comment: This works great! But I'd still like to figure out why the setInterval isn't working as it 'should'. I'll accept this in a couple hours if nothing else gets posted.

Comment: It's the second time I fall into the `setInterval()` trap. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xwecq/). It works on Google Chrome and Firefox just as you expected. Can you confirm this snippet is not working on your machine?

I made few tiny changes:

- AJAX call to `/echo/json`
- Smaller interval (50 ms)
- function reference: `setInterval(CheckProgress, 5000)` instead of string with JavaScript

Interval function is called few times and is cleared once `echo` service AJAX call returns. Exactly how you want it to be.

Can you reproduce the problem there?

Comment: No I can't reproduce the problem in that jsfiddle. It works as I'd expect :( Do you think the fact that I'm working in an MVC3 app has anything to do with why it isn't working?