# asp.net javascript memory leak in IE9 standards mode only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, memory, internet-explorer-9, memory-leaks

I'm experiencing a memory leak when using javascript to automatically refresh the page every X seconds.  I have verified that this leak is not happening in Firefox or in Chrome, and its also not happening in IE 7/8/10 - only IE 9 (i'm on Win7).

What's crazy to me is that when I'm looking at this in IE9 and watching the memory usage creep up, I can open the developer tools in IE, change the browser mode to IE8, and the memory stops creeping up as the page continues to reload.  Change it back to IE9 mode and it starts rising again.

The sample page below is a mock-up showing the leak, but the page I'm experiencing it on is a monitoring page which I leave open most of the day.  If I leave this page open for several hours in IE9, it eventually uses up all of the memory that the 32-bit application can access (~1.5Gb), and then IE becomes unresponsive.

I have looked at this sample page with [drip-0.5](http://www.outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [IEJSLeaksDetector](http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2.aspx) - but both of those leak finders are based on IE7 rendering engine where this is not a problem.  And both of those tools show no problems.

What can I do to mitigate this (other than just using a different browser), or is there anything I can do?

Sample .aspx file is below.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sec = 15;
    function pageLoad() {
        setInterval(updReload, 1000);
    }
    function updReload() {
        if (sec == 0) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('spnReload').innerHTML = sec--;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <h1>Current Time is: <%=Now.ToShortTimeString() %></h1>
        Reload in: <span id="spnReload"></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**
Here's a new wrinkle I just discovered:  IE9 Quirks mode does not seem to have the leak - only IE9 Standards mode.  Even when I set the Browser mode to IE8, if the Document mode is IE9 Standards - the memory leak is present.

---

**Update2:**
I tried to recreate this sample page in a classic ASP file, and it did NOT exhibit the memory leak shown in my sample file above.  So then I started thinking that it may be related to .NET's own javascript functions..  I commented out the `ScriptManager` and added the `onload="pageLoad()"` to the body tag, and the memory leak dropped from 1-2 MB per reload down to about 80 KB per reload!  Updated code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sec = 15;
    function pageLoad() {
        setTimeout(updReload, 1000);
    }
    function updReload() {
        if (sec == 0) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('spnReload').innerHTML = --sec;
            setTimeout(updReload, 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="pageLoad()">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />--%>
        <h1>Current Time is: <%=Now.ToShortTimeString() %></h1>
        Reload in: <span id="spnReload"></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Still leaking slightly, but I could probably live with that..  the problem is my production page that this is happening on is a content page whose master page contains the ScriptManager..  I guess I'll have to remove it via code in the Page_Load if that is the resolution I have to go with.

Anybody else experiencing 1-2 MB memory leak with .NET 4.0 ScriptManager Javascripts?

Anything else I could do to get around the leak and leave the ScriptManager on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606375/ie9-memory-leak

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that post several times today b/c it sounds so similar to what I'm experiencing.  However the accepted answer there talks about circular references in the javascript..   I dont have any circular refs in the code I posted above, yet the leak still exists -- but as I recently discovered, it only exists in IE9 Standards mode, not Quirks mode

Comment: Hi Stephen, Did you find a way to solve this issue? We are also facing a same kind of problem. Your latest findings would help us to mitigate the issue quickly.

Comment: @Raathigesh - No, I did not ever find a fix.  The best I could do is set a Meta tag in the page header to tell IE to always render as IE8.  That way, the memory leak was not present (or at least was greatly reduced).  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

Comment: @Stephen - We also didn't get the time to investigate further. Finally we also emulated as IE 8. Thanks you for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you should explicitly stop the interval.

clearInterval( sec );

When 15 is reached.

Comment: I got my hopes up when I read this b/c it makes sense - even though the interval should be cleared when the page reloads - that maybe that is not happening the way it should.  I updated the code to grab the intervalID, and then clear that ID before reloading the page - no difference.  Still leaking memory in standards mode, still holding steady in quirks mode

Comment: Also, based on an SO answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7560338/470360, I tried taking the interval out and using setTimeout() for each iteration, and that as well has not changed anything for me..  :(